# how to delete element from hash where stored array of hashes in vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, hash

There my json object which I display at page. And I want to delete/add hash in one of the arrays in hash "costs". My post requests work well and changes json object but at web page they not changes if I don't push refresh button (F5).

```
{  
   "costs":{  
      "2018-11-01 00:00:00 +0600":[  
         {  
            "id":39,
            "cost_name":"asd",
            "user_id":2,
            "fix":true,
            "amount":123,
            "created_at":"2018-11-13T16:48:32.603+06:00",
            "updated_at":"2018-11-13T16:48:32.603+06:00"
         },
         {  
            "id":20,
            "cost_name":"Rent office",
            "user_id":2,
            "fix":true,
            "amount":300000,
            "created_at":"2018-11-09T18:00:27.567+06:00",
            "updated_at":"2018-11-09T18:10:16.607+06:00"
         }
      ],
      "2018-09-01 00:00:00 +0600":[  
         {  
            "id":19,
            "cost_name":"internet",
            "user_id":9,
            "fix":true,
            "amount":15000,
            "created_at":"2018-09-07T18:36:19.108+06:00",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-07T18:36:19.108+06:00"
         },
         {  
            "id":18,
            "cost_name":"Rent office",
            "user_id":2,
            "fix":true,
            "amount":17000,
            "created_at":"2018-09-06T18:36:19.108+06:00",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-06T18:36:19.108+06:00"
         }
      ]
   }
```

When there no arrays like "2018-11-01 00:00:00 +0600" I just delete with this code:

```
.then(response => this.costs.splice(this.costs.indexOf(cost), 1))
```

and add with that code:

```
costs.unshift(this.cost)
```

But after I separate costs by month structure of json was change and those codes does't work

there my variables in vue:

```
data () {
return {
  error: '',
  notice: '',
  costs: [],

  cost: {
    id: '',
    cost_name: '',
    user_id: '',
    fix: '',
    amount: ''
  }
}


}
```

Comment: please explain more your use case

Comment: You will need to determine which month it occurs in before deciding where to delete it. If you have the dates available then you can do this. But it strikes me as an odd structure, it sounds like your old structure was better and easier to work with. What was the reason for changing it like this?

Comment: For example how can I delete hash with "id":19 @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: i think you need something like `myarray=myarray.filter(item=>return item.id!=19)`